# Unity IOC container and how to resolve different instances of the same interface

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container

I have a unity container that I am registering types within like so:

```
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
.RegisterType<ITaxAuthorityRateService, TaxAuthorityPopulationRateService>( "PopulationRate" )
.RegisterType<ITaxAuthorityRateService, TaxAuthorityBusinessLicenseRateService>( "BusinessLicenseRate" );
```

Then I also want to register 2 different services that take a ITaxAuthorityRateService variable in their constructor. Both services need a different class that derives from ITaxAuthorityRateService. How can I handle that situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Keeping the names the same during registration is correct ("PopulationRate" and "BusinessLicenseRate"). All I had to do was add an attribute to the ITaxAuthorityRateService parameter within the constructor of each service like so:

Service1 constructor parameter:

```
[Dependency( "BusinessLicenseRate" )]
ITaxAuthorityRateService rateService
```

Service2 constructor parameter:

```
[Dependency( "PopulationRate" )]
ITaxAuthorityRateService rateService
```

And then each service received the correct ITaxAuthorityRateService instance.