# Unity MVC3 Controller Constructor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity IOC container and how to resolve different instances of the same interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343532/unity-ioc-container-and-how-to-resolve-different-instances-of-the-same-interface)

I have a controller constructor that has two parameters that implement the same interface shown below. I have tried to register these types in Unity also shown below but I have run into a problem.

***Controller Constructor***

```
public ControlController(IAdapter daveAdapter, IAdapter bobAdapter)
{
        DaveAdapter = daveAdapter;
        BobAdapter = bobAdapter;
}
```

***Unity registration***

```
 container
.RegisterType<IAdapter, DaveAdapter>()
.RegisterType<IAdapter, BobAdapter>()
```

When the controller is constructed both adapters are resolved as DaveAdapter's instead of one Dave and one Bob. How can I tell unity to differentiate between the two adapters so that the controller has an adapter of each type?

Comment: i don't know Unity but Ninject allows bindings according to parameter name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `InjectionConstructor` and  `ResolvedParameter` objects in registering controller:

```
.RegisterType<IAdapter, DaveAdapter>()
.RegisterType<IAdapter, BobAdapter>("Bob")

.RegisterType<ControlController, ControlController>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
      new ResolvedParameter<IAdapter>(),
      new ResolvedParameter<IAdapter>("Bob")
))
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do the trick!
Never thought of registering the controller and using an injection constructor! :D